# SwiftUI Stack Layout

Tags: text, layout, swiftui, stack

I need to implement view with two texts, and first text alignment need to be trailing, and second text alignment leading, but I have this..
please help me to build correct layout.
i tried to put another VStack inside the HStack and assign the trailing orientation to the first and the leading to the second

[image]

this is my code example:

```
 var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("test1")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
//                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                Text("testtest1")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 12, trailing: 0))
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("test23")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
//                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                Text(String("testtest12"))
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 12, trailing: 0))
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("test345")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(alignment: .trailing)
//                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                Text("testtest1234")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 12, trailing: 0))
            HStack {
                Text("test6789")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
//                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                Text("testtest123456")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 12, trailing: 0))
            HStack {
                Text("test01234")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
//                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                Text("testtest56")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 12, trailing: 0))
            HStack {
                Text("test5")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
//                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                Text("testtes78")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 40, bottom: 12, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
```

But I want to make something like this:

[image]

Comment: perhaps https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-the-swiftui-grid-layout/ might be of interest

Comment: " i tried to put another VStack inside the HStack and assign the trailing orientation to the first and the leading to the second"

Answer (score 1):

Give the texts on the left fixed width and add the multiLineAlignment(.traling) to all.

Edit:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0..<5) { i in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Left Text \(String(repeating: "XX", count: i))")
                    .font(.system(size: 12).bold())
                    .frame(width: 150, alignment: .trailing)
                    .padding(.trailing, 15)
                Text("Right Text \(i)")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                            .stroke(.red)
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Although this seems like a good solution, I think it would be nicer to add code to support the answer.

Comment: please, add the code

Comment: @user14300555 I added example code and preview.